# Odoo debug application

Tags: odoo

I am starting to learn odoo and i come from PHP background. so while debugging the PHP framework, i know the controller and methods being called by looking the web address ( http://host/ {controller} / {method} / {parameter} )

I don't know how this work in Odoo as i see ( http://host:8069/web?db={db}#page={page}&limit=80&view_type={view_type}&model={model}&action={action_id} ). also some time ( http://host:8069/web?db={db}#view_type=kanban&model={model}&menu_id={menu_id}&action=176 )

Can someone please guide me how it works, only high level.

Really appreciate.

Thanks,
M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your have asked a very  genuine query:

As you said in php we follow this pattern while making the routes and controllers:

`http://host/ {controller} / {method} / {parameter}` .

> Main objective for making such pattern is to make the **unique URI** for
>   each resource.

Here in odoo there is no as such restrication about placing controller/method in the url route.

odoo give you the freedom/power to make the route and  as you know the power always come with responsibility,
so its the developer responsibility to  ensure that no two route conflict with each other.

At the same time the url should SEO friendly too .

> In Our team we usually flow  **module/model/method** .

For example  :
i have A:

- module name `academy`
- module have a model teachers[`_name='academy.teacher'`]
- module have a model students[`_name='academy.student'`]
- module have a model courses[`_name='academy.course'`]
- For displaying the list of  teachers in the grid view  we create the
  url pattern like: `/academy/teachers`
- For displaying the list the  individual  teacher we create the url
  pattern like: `/academy/teacher`
- for creating the teacher: `/academy/teacher/create`
- For displaying the list of  students in the grid view  we create the
  url pattern like :`/academy/students`
- For displaying the list the  individual  teacher we create the url
  pattern like :`/academy/student`
- For displaying the list of  courses in the grid view  we create the
  url pattern like `/academy/courses`
- For displaying the list the  individual  teacher we create the url
  pattern like: `/academy/course`

**Let's a an live example**:

- For displaying  the order [`/shop/cart`](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/website_sale/controllers/main.py#L334)

  ```
     @http.route(['/shop/cart'], type='http', auth="public", methods=['POST'], website=True)
     def cart(self, product_id, add_qty=1, set_qty=0, **kw):
       pass
  ```
- For updating  the order  [`/shop/cart/update`:](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/website_sale/controllers/main.py#L364)

  ```
    @http.route(['/shop/cart/update'], type='http', auth="public", methods=['POST'], website=True)
    def cart_update(self, product_id, add_qty=1, set_qty=0, **kw):
      pass
  ```
- In case if you want to create a json request handler `type='json'` for
  shop cart update   [`/shop/cart/update_json`](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/website_sale/controllers/main.py#L369)

  ```
   @http.route(['/shop/cart/update_json'], type='json', auth="public", methods=['POST'], website=True)
   def cart_update_json(self, product_id, line_id=None, add_qty=None, set_qty=None, display=True):
     pass
  ```

As you said you are a fresher i would also suggest you few useful link :

1. **[FOR ODOO GuideLine.](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/guidelines.html)**
2. [**FOR ODOO WEBSITE MODULE**](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/website.html)
3. [**FOR ODOO Http handler**](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/http.html)
4. [**FOR ODOO BACKED MODULE**](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/backend.html)

Hope this may help you in understating the URL pattern of ODOO.

Comment: Thanks Prakash, I created a custom module named test, under that controllers, models, templates are under controllers, models, data folders. in my __openerp__.py, data field is set to 'data/templates.xml'. now i am rendering the template from controller using return http.request.render('test.listing',{ }). in my data/templates.xml, i have <template id='listing'><h1>hello</h1></template> with data and openerp tags above them. when i run this i get error ' QWebTemplateNotFound: External ID not found in system: test.listing '. Can you please help me what i am doing wrong. Really Appreciate.

Comment: include data/templates.xml. in opener.py and restart your server

Comment: Hi Prakash, I have included the file in __openerp__.py as:        'data' :['data/templates.xml']